# Was what Joi did with the hooker a normal function of her system?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

At first I thought that this was some creative thing that Joi came up with but now it occurs to me that her synching must be a feature that many people use who own their own Joi -- when they occasionally want to have simulated sex with their Joi, they hire a hooker and Joi knows how to synch. This is sort of like the steak and fries thing -- this is just part of her repertoire. This is not to say that Joi is limited to only pre-programmed behavior -- she is a true intelligence, even a consciousness perhaps.

Comment: _"[Joi] is a true intelligence, even a consciousness perhaps"_: I think the movie is ambiguous about this, and in fact provides some evidence to the contrary...

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out in [my (somewhat unrelated) question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/103005/why-did-the-joi-advertisement-trigger-k) yes, Joi is just a very elaborately designed program. She is designed to react to things in particular ways; to ultimately bring happiness, or "Joy" to her owner/partner; however that may be required.

As we can see, the many different ways that she does this is by the constant affection she provides, the bolstering of his ego, the "homeliness" she creates in his apartment, etc.

As the movie goes on, K starts to build a connection with other people, such as the Captain, and the Hooker, Joi provides that for him, as that is what he appears to be reacting positively to.